# How do I make Gradle rerun a task when its dependencies are run?

Tags: gradle

Let's say that I have a task "main" that depends on another task "dependency." I would like "main" to be rerun any time its dependency (or its dependency's dependencies) is rebuilt because "main" relies on the artifacts produced by "dependency" (or the dependencies of "dependency").

A `build.gradle` file containing an example of what I'm dealing with is the following:

```
defaultTasks 'main'

task baseDependency {
    outputs.file 'deps.out'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'echo hello world > deps.out'
        }
    }
}

task dependency(dependsOn: baseDependency)

task main(dependsOn: dependency) {
    outputs.file 'main.out'
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'echo hello world > main.out'
        }
    }
}
```

Executing `gradle` the first time:

```
:baseDependency
:dependency
:main

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.623 secs
```

Executing it a second time:

```
:baseDependency
:dependency
:main UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.709 secs
```

I would *really love* if "main" were **not** marked "UP-TO-DATE" if its dependencies had to be rebuilt. That seems essential. How do you make sure that's the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to [specify dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) between tasks is via task's inputs and outputs. This can be any file, fileset or directory. 
In your case you should modify `main` task and add `inputs.file 'deps.out'` to its definition.

Note that gradle has an optimization that may lead to unexpected behavior in a simplistic example that you provided.

> Before a task is executed for the first time, Gradle takes a snapshot
>   of the inputs. This snapshot contains the set of input files and a
>   hash of the contents of each file. Gradle then executes the task. If
>   the task completes successfully, Gradle takes a snapshot of the
>   outputs. This snapshot contains the set of output files and a hash of
>   the contents of each file. Gradle persists both snapshots for the next
>   time the task is executed.
>
> Each time after that, before the task is executed, Gradle takes a new
>   snapshot of the inputs and outputs. If the new snapshots are the same
>   as the previous snapshots, Gradle assumes that the outputs are up to
>   date and skips the task. If they are not the same, Gradle executes the
>   task. Gradle persists both snapshots for the next time the task is
>   executed.

So even if you specify correct inputs in a simple example where the same file is generated the dependent task will be marked as up to date on the second and subsequent runs.

If you do not want or cannot hardcode dependency on the file you can override `upToDateWhen` for dependent task and calculate the condition if the task is up to date based on [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getTaskDependencies()) of this task and their [state](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskState.html) like this:

```
outputs.upToDateWhen { task ->
   task.taskDependencies.inject(true) { r, dep ->
     r && dep.values.inject(true) { res, v ->
        res && (!(v instanceof Task) || v?.state.getSkipped())
     }
   }
}
```

`upToDateWhen` should return `true` if this task should not be run at all (because its output are already up-to-date). And this is the case when no dependent task was run (the gradle documentation is a bit vague about this I must admit but `getSkipped` seems work as expected).

Comment: I've elaborated upon my examples. Also I don't want to hardcode the input like that, but `dependency.output.files` doesn't actually work in my case because the immediate dependency doesn't always produce the output I need. It may be a task that just aggregates other tasks, for example.

Comment: I've added the last paragraph for generic solution based on `upToDateWhen`.

Comment: Would you mind including example code? I'm unclear about the semantics of `upToDateWhen` and whether I should be using `getDidWork` or `getExecuted`, or inverting one of `getSkipped` or `getUpToDate`. Which would get me what I'm interested in? And is this the expected way to handle things? It seems really surprising to me there's no simple, standard way to say that a task depends on the outputs of the tasks in its `dependsOn` chain.